# how to work on order by relationship column in adonisJs v5?

Tags: typescript, adonis.js, lucid

I have implement the following query in adonisjs v4 :

```
const services = await Service
  .query()
  .with('categories')
  .orderBy('categories.id', 'desc')
  .fetch()
```

It's work fine.

how to i implement the relation column order_by in adonis v5 **preload()**.

Comment: `const services = await Service
  .query()
  .preload('categories',(query) => query.orderBy('columnName','desc'))
  .orderBy('categories.id', 'desc')
  .fetch()` there is a callback method in preload. [here](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/models/relationships#preload-relationship)

Comment: @danish-khan-I show the error [Unknown column 'categories.id' in 'order clause']

Comment: `const services = await Service   .query()   .preload('categories',(query) => query.orderBy('columnName','desc'))  .fetch()` just noticed you had order by on outer query instead of relationship, so I just removed it from there.

Comment: `const chats = await Chat.query()   .preload('messages',(query) => query.orderBy('columnName','desc'))  .fetch()`

i can try depend on message table column order_by chats list.

Comment: `const services = await Service   .query()   .preload('categories',(query) => query.orderBy('columnName','desc'))  .fetch()`

if ican use the query than order_by chats list. don't format our chat list.